# Can I use CSS child selectors as jquery selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using this as a jquery selector: #menuleft ul.AspNet-Menu > li.AspNet-Menu-Leaf (it's a border-radius enabling script for IE - called PIE) but I don't know if I can actually do this in jquery? Do I need to use .children instead?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Of course JQuery uses the css selectors. See [JQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery does support the child selector.

`$('#menuleft ul.AspNet-Menu > li.AspNet-Menu-Leaf')` should work.

[jQuery documentation: Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Any css selector should work with jquery

Comment: This is not entirely true. See http://ejohn.org/blog/selectors-that-people-actually-use